# getint() function multiply by 10?

Tags: c

I have a question about a part of the getint program.

When we got this part:

```
for(*pn = 0; isdigit(c); c = getch())
    *pn = 10 * *pn + (c - '0');
```

First it converts `c` to its real numeric value, then it multiply the data inside `pn` with 10.
Why does it multiply 10 with the data inside `pn`?

Regards,

Ken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is starting from the left, and multiplying by 10 for each successive digit it encounters as it moves to the right.

Take the string "234" for example:

1. On the first iteration, take the 2. Multiply the 0 (`*pn`) by 10, add 2, you get 2.
2. On the second iteration, take the 3. Multiply the 2 (`*pn`) by 10, add 3, you get 23.
3. On the third iteration, take the 4. Multiply the 23 (`*pn`) by 10, add 4, you get 234.

Comment: Thanks man! Your example really gave me an idea of why it does so!

Answer (score 2):

any number in the decimal notation can be expressed as a polynomial in `10`

```
234 = 2*10^2 + 3*10 + 4
```

reading from the left and multiplying by `10` assures each digit ends up multiplying the correct power of `10`. It's just an application of Horners rule, really.

Comment: (`234 = 2*10^2 + 3*10^1 + 4*10^0`)

Answer (score 1):

The function is reading one digit at a time, starting from the left. So if it's reading, say, `12`, then first it gets `c == '1'` and `*pn == 0`, it adds `1` to `*pn` and now `*pn` is `1`. For each successive digit, it multiplies the existing value by ten (`*pn` is now `10`) and adds the digit (`*pn` is now `12`). This way it reads one digit at a time and ends up with the correct integer.